# "On-screen" usage as an adverb and/or prepositional phrase

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, definition

I want to use the phrase "on-screen" correctly, so I have looked it up on online dictionaries and found it defined as an **adverb or adjective** but **not a prepositional phrase** which is a bit confusing considering the results I found in [*Google Books*](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&biw=1496&bih=762&tbm=bks&ei=tG4JXYHBB5uBhbIP8piU4AU&btnG=Search&q=on-screen) and the example in the [*Collins Dictionary*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-screen) which is:

> adverb
>
> 3. on a screen, esp a computer screen
>
> *A simple help menu is available **on-screen**.*

If it is an adverb in the example above, then what does it change/describe?

---

In the [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-screen), it means:

> On-screen: adjective, adverb [ not gradable ] US
>
> on the screen of a television or computer:
>
> *I easily adjusted the colors by using the **on-screen** menu.*

As it means literally *on the screen of a computer*, would the sentence be correct if it was rewritten like this:

> I easily adjusted the colors by using the menu **on-screen**.

***?***

Does in its original version act as an adjective, and would it act in the second one as an *adverb* or *prepositional phrase*?

---

The sentence I want to use the phrase in:

> Her eyes would be set **on-screen**.

Is this a correct usage of the phrase, and what would it function as?

Comment: In your sentence do you want to say that her eyes were looking at the screen?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to convey.

Comment: Then I agree with David Siegel's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "on-screen" pretty much always means "something dsiplayed on the screen of a computer" (or in some cases a television or movie screen). Metaphorically, it can mean "directly visible" as in

> The character Jones never kills anyone on-screen, but we learn of several off-screen killings.

This form could be used even of a novel, where of course nothign is truly displayed on the screen, because there is no screen. "on-stage" can be used in a simialor metaphorical way.

But if you mean:

> Her eyes were looking intently at the computer screen.

Then "on-screen" should not be used, as her eyes are never displayed on the screen Instead, you could say:

> - Her eyes would be focused on the screen.
> - She was staring intently at the screen.
> - Her gaze seemed locked on the screen
> - Her eyes would be set on the screen.
> - Her eyes would be fixed on the screen.

or any of several other possibilities. All the above have very simialr meanings.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will definitely go with one of your suggestions, but I want to know if my sentence with the proper correction would become valid, I think *set* is more or less an equivalent of *focused* so it would be: **Her eyes would be set on the screen**. What do you think?

Comment: @Tas Yes, that works. I've added it to the answer. There are quite a few other possibilities with much the same meaning, too many to list them all.